# HttpContext.Current is null in api call when running in a azure worker role

Tags: c#, owin, azure-worker-roles

I'm trying to use Httpcontext.Current to get to my owin context in a method (that is called by the controller), this works perfectly when running the site in IIS. The problem only exists when I run my api as a Azure worker role. Even if I add a breakpoint in my controller and try to get HttpContext.Current I still get null.

My question is: Is there something extra I need to add when using azure? Or does worker roles not support this approach?

Comment: I doubt that `HttpContext.Current` works if the site is self-hosted. Have you actually verified that?

Comment: Actually no. I confused this api with another service. I'll edit my question. You think this is why it's not working? Since running a owin api in a worker role is more or less the same as running it selfhosted.

Comment: Yeap, precisely. You should forget about `HttpContext.Current` in OWIN enabled applications. The fact that it might work in IIS doesn't mean that you should use it because you are killing all the benefits of OWIN and coupling your code with ASP.NET host.

Comment: Okay, well now I know where to go look for more info. If you add an answer I'll take it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the Azure worker role uses some specific OWIN host where `HttpContext.Current` is not available. The `HttpContext.Current` is available only inside an ASP.NET host.